# How to get form input, using javascript and jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am using php for filling some data in below div tag

```
<div id="div_content">
<?=$text_content?>
</div>
```

from the below form contents

```
    <form action="javascript:fill_content(parm)"> 
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><textarea name='content_name' id='content_id'>This is a test</textarea> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <input name='form_submit' type="submit" value='submit'>
    </form>
```

I used jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fill_content(textarea_content) {
  $('#div_content').load('/process.php?content=' + textarea_content);
}
</script>
```

How can i get `textarea` value in `javascript:fill_content(parm)` as `parm`.

I used `document.getElementByID('content_id').value` and also `document.getElementsByName('content_name')[0]` instead of `parm`, but they did not work.

Many Thanks.

Comment: `action` is not an event, when do you want to call the function, on form _submit_?

Comment: Yes, when form submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 fill_content($("#content_id").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jQuery again to address the textarea? U can use $('#div_content').find('#content_id').val()